# couldn't fetch session value to another page

Tags: php, html, session

I'm just started in php so I'm still newbie, I do have a question. why my adminSearchPage.php can't fetch session value from loginProcess.php, even though all the necessary code for sessions are there,I tried to change the connection to loginProcess.php page still cannot work, if someone could help me to solve this, I'll really appreciate this, sorry for my bad grammar.

adminSearchPage.php

```
<?php
// session begin
session_start();
//connect to database
include "database_conn.php";
//check whether user logged in
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])&& $_SESSION['userName'] == $_SESSION['userName'])
{

}
else 
{
    echo "please login first!";
    die($_SESSION['userName']);
    header("refresh:5;url=loginPage.html");
    exit();
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link id="pagestyle" href="adminSearchPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>
<body id="background">
    <div class="wrapper1">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="homePage.html" accesskey="h">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="adminEventlist.php" accesskey="v">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="adminSearchPage.php" accesskey="s">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="b">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="adminLogoutPage.php" accesskey="l">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2">
<table>
    <?php


        $output1 = '';
        $output2 = '';
        $error = '';
        //search by title
        if(isset($_POST['title']))
        {   
            //get value from form
            $srTitle = $_POST['title'];
            //sql statement
            $sqlSrTitle = "SELECT * 
                            FROM te_events,te_category,te_venue 
                            WHERE te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND te_events.eventTitle LIKE '%$srTitle%'";
            // query sql statement 
            $srTitleQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSrTitle) or DIE (mysqli_error($conn));
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($srTitleQuery);

            if($count == 0)//for search record unexist in database
            {
                $error = "there was no search results!";
            }
            else
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($srTitleQuery))
                {   
                    $eID = $row['eventID'];
                    $eTitle = $row['eventTitle'];
                    $eCat = $row['catDesc'];
                    $eVenue = $row['venueName'];
                    $eLocation = $row['location'];
                    $ePrice = $row['eventPrice'];

                    $output2 .= "
                            <tr>
                                <th><p>Event ID</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Title</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Category</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Venue</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Price</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Location</p></th>\n
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>$eID</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eTitle</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eCat</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eVenue</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$ePrice</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eLocation</p></td>
                            </tr>\n";
                }
            }
        }

        //search by id
        if(isset($_POST['eventID']))
        {
            //get value from form
            $srID = $_POST['eventID'];
            //sql statement 
            $sqlSrID = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events, te_category, te_venue
                        WHERE te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND te_events.eventID = '$srID'
                        ";
            //query sql statement
            $sqlIDQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSrID) or DIE (mysqli_error($conn));
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($sqlIDQuery);

            if($count == 0)// for search record unexist in database
            {
                $error = "there was no search results!";
            }
            else
            {   
                //get value 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlIDQuery))
                {   
                    $eID = $row['eventID'];
                    $eTitle = $row['eventTitle'];
                    $eCat = $row['catDesc'];
                    $eVenue = $row['venueName'];
                    $eLocation = $row['location'];
                    $ePrice = $row['eventPrice'];

                    $output2 .= "
                            <tr>
                                <th><p>Event ID</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Title</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Category</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Venue</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Price</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Location</p></th>\n
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>$eID</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eTitle</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eCat</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eVenue</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$ePrice</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eLocation</p></td>
                            </tr>\n";
                }
            }
        }
        //search by category
        if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {   
            // get value from search form 
            $catID = $_POST['category'];
            //sql statement for search category 
            $sqlCat = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events,te_venue,te_category
                        WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND
                        te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.catID = '$catID'";
            // query sql statement
            $sqlCatQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCat) or DIE (mysqli_error($conn));
            // get value
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlCatQuery))
            {
                $eID = $row['eventID'];
                $eTitle = $row['eventTitle'];
                $eCat = $row['catDesc'];
                $eVenue = $row['venueName'];
                $eLocation = $row['location'];
                $ePrice = $row['eventPrice'];

                $output2 .= "
                            <tr>
                                <th><p>Event ID</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Title</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Category</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Venue</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Price</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Location</p></th>\n
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>$eID</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eTitle</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eCat</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eVenue</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$ePrice</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eLocation</p></td>
                            </tr>\n";
            }                   
        }

        //search by price range
        if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {
            $price = $_POST['price'];

            if ($price == 0)
            {
                $error = "";
            }
            else
            {
                if ($price == 1)//sql for search price between 0 to 10
                {
                    $sqlPrice = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events,te_category,te_venue
                        WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND
                        te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.eventPrice >= 0 AND te_events.eventPrice <= 10
                        ORDER BY te_events.eventPrice";
                }
                elseif ($price == 2)//sql search for price between 10 to 20
                {
                    $sqlPrice = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events,te_category,te_venue
                        WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND
                        te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.eventPrice >= 10 AND te_events.eventPrice <= 20
                        ORDER BY te_events.eventPrice";
                }
                elseif ($price == 3)//sql search for price between 20 to 30
                {
                    $sqlPrice = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events,te_category,te_venue
                        WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND
                        te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.eventPrice >= 20 AND te_events.eventPrice <= 30
                        ORDER BY te_events.eventPrice";
                }
                elseif ($price == 4)//sql search for price between 30 to 40
                {
                    $sqlPrice = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events,te_category,te_venue
                        WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND
                        te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.eventPrice >= 30 AND te_events.eventPrice <= 40
                        ORDER BY te_events.eventPrice";
                }
                elseif ($price == 5)//sql search for price between 40 to 50
                {
                    $sqlPrice = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events,te_category,te_venue
                        WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND
                        te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.eventPrice >= 40 AND te_events.eventPrice <= 50
                        ORDER BY te_events.eventPrice";
                }
                elseif ($price == 6)//sql search for price between 50 to 60
                {
                    $sqlPrice = "SELECT * 
                        FROM te_events,te_category,te_venue
                        WHERE te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID AND
                        te_events.catID = te_category.catID AND te_events.eventPrice >= 50 AND te_events.eventPrice <= 60
                        ORDER BY te_events.eventPrice";
                }
                // query the sql statement
                $sqlPriceQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPrice) or DIE (mysqli_error($conn));
                // get value
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlPriceQuery))
                {
                    $eID = $row['eventID'];
                    $eTitle = $row['eventTitle'];
                    $eCat = $row['catDesc'];
                    $eVenue = $row['venueName'];
                    $eLocation = $row['location'];
                    $ePrice = $row['eventPrice'];

                    $output2 .= "
                            <tr>
                                <th><p>Event ID</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Title</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Category</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Venue</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Price</p></th>\n
                                <th><p>Event Location</p></th>\n
                            </tr>\n
                            <tr>
                                <td><p>$eID</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eTitle</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eCat</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eVenue</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$ePrice</p></td>\n
                                <td><p>$eLocation</p></td>
                            </tr>\n";               
                }
            }
        }


    ?>
    </table>
    <form action="adminSearchPage.php" method="POST" value="search">
        <table>
        <caption><h3>Search Event<h3></caption>
            <tr><td>Event Title</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="title" placeholder="search events..."></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Event ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="eventID" placeholder="search event ID..."></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Event Price</td>
                <td>    
                    <?php
                        echo "<select name=\"price\">\n";
                            echo "<option value=\"0\">Select range of price...</option>\n";
                            echo "<option value=\"1\">0.0 - 10.00</option>\n";
                            echo "<option value=\"2\">10.0 - 20.00</option>\n";
                            echo "<option value=\"3\">20.0 - 30.00</option>\n";
                            echo "<option value=\"4\">30.0 - 40.00</option>\n";
                            echo "<option value=\"5\">40.0 - 50.00</option>\n";
                            echo "<option value=\"6\">50.0 - 60.00</option>\n";
                        echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Event Category</td>
                <td><?php
                        $sqlCategory ="SELECT * FROM te_category ORDER BY 1";//sql statement 
                        $rsCategory = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCategory) or DIE (mysqli_error($conn));//sql query

                        $sqlMatchCat ="SELECT catID FROM te_events ORDER BY 1";//sql statement 
                        $sqlMatchCatQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlMatchCat) or DIE (mysqli_error($conn));//sql match query

                        echo"<select name=\"category\" >\n";
                        echo"<option value=\"0\">select category...</option>\n";
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsCategory))
                        {   // populate select item
                            $catID = $row['catID'];
                            $catDesc = $row['catDesc'];
                            // get each certificate record  
                            if($catID == $sqlMatchCatQuery)
                            { echo "<option value =\"$catID\" selected>$catDesc</option>\n"; }
                            else
                            { echo "<option value =\"$catID\">$catDesc</option>\n"; }
                        }
                        echo "</select>\n";
                        mysqli_free_result($rsCategory);// remove result set
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Event Date</td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="search" type="submit" value="search"></input></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <?php
                echo "$output1";
                echo "$output2";
                echo "$error";
            ?>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper1">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="homePage.html" accesskey="h">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="adminEventlist.php" accesskey="v">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="adminSearchPage.php" accesskey="s">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="b">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="adminLogoutPage.php" accesskey="l">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

loginProcess.php

```
<?php
ini_set("session.save_path", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../sessionData");
// session begin
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Process</title>
<link id="pagestyle" href="loginProcess.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body id="background">
<div id="wrapper2">
<?php
    $userName   = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'userName') ? $_POST['userName']: null;
    $passWD     = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST,'pwd')      ? $_POST['pwd']     : null;

    // sanitize part, saniziting data input from user 
    $userName = trim($userName);
    $userName = filter_var($userName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    $userName = filter_var($userName, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    $passWD = trim($passWD);
    $passWD = filter_var($passWD, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    $passWD = filter_var($passWD, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    //database connection
    include 'database_conn.php';
    //SQL statement for user login
    //query the te_users database table to get the passwordHash for username entered by user in login process
    $sqlUser = "SELECT passwordHash FROM te_users WHERE username = ?";
    //Query sql statement
    $sqlUserStmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sqlUser);
    //bind the entered $userName to prepare statement, s is the datatype
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sqlUserStmt,"s",$userName);
    //execute query 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sqlUserStmt);
    // get passwordHash form the query results for entered username and store it in the variable indicated
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sqlUserStmt,$passWDHash);
    //check if a record returned by the query
    $errorList = array();
    if(empty($userName))
    {
        echo "<p>Please enter the user name</p>\n";
        header("refresh:2;url=loginPage.html");
        echo "you will be redirected to login form within 3 seconds";
    }

    if(empty($passWD))
    {
        echo "<p>Please enter the Password</p>\n";
        header("refresh:2;url=loginPage.html");
        echo "you will be redirected to login form within 3 seconds";
    }
    else 
    {
        if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($sqlUserStmt))
        {
            //declare variable 
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            // check password 
            if(password_verify($passWD,$passWDHash))
            {
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                echo "<p>hello! <p>\n";
            }
            else 
            {
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
                echo "<p>Password incorrect!</p>\n";
                header("refresh:2;url=loginPage.html");
                echo "you will be redirected to login form within 3 seconds";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<p>User doesn't exist!</p>\n";
            header("refresh:2;url=loginPage.html");
            echo "you will be redirected to login form within 3 seconds";
        }
    }
    //closing statement
    // closing connection
    mysqli_stmt_close($sqlUserStmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    // print out wellcome when admin log in 
    if((isset($_SESSION['userName'])) && ($_SESSION['loggedin'] = true))
    {

        echo "<p>Welcome home ". $_SESSION['userName'] ."</p>\n";
        header("refresh:2;url=adminEventlist.php");
    }
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $_SESSION['userName'];
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I remember, `session_start()` MUST be the very first command in each page it appears.

Comment: i trid to move session_start() in loginProcess.php to the top, but the session restricted file didn't created

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to write this directory you are using to store your session data?

Comment: yes i do, the file showed up when i put the ini_set at the top

Comment: It's been a long time since I used PHP, then I'm trying to remember some possible causes for this here. Have you set your session's path at `php.ini`?

Comment: if by chance is this one what you mean, 
ini_set("session.save_path", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../sessionData"); then i set it already

Comment: No, thatś not what I mean. I had seen this command in your code, of course. I mean at `php.ini` file, the default configuration file..

Comment: how i do set the php.ini? may you help me?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_ini_configuration.htm

Comment: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/what-is-php-ini

Comment: i found my php.ini file in my xampp directory, and all functions relating to session are on